# Send Notification to users of android application on click of a button

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications

> I want to send notification on Click of a button to those users(of my
>   application) who is in 5km of radius from me, and on opening the
>   notification it should display the current location of the person who
>   clicked the button,  i tried it using Parse.com but still confused, in
>   case of sending notification on click of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GeoPoints , First create a ParseGeoPoint, then query using whereWithinKilometers to find all the users within the specified range , finally send the push notifications containing the original location.

Comment: ThanQ :), can you explain what will be in onClick Method?

Comment: @user3262810 in the onclick method you will have to query and send the notifications , learn about geo points here --> https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints